# How do I kill Flash orphaned processes?

Tags: linux, scripting, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 11.04.  Periodically, I need to clean up orphaned Flash processes that resemble

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 R selenium 25949     1 54  80   0 - 19187 -      00:09 ?        05:26:03 /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer.bin --plugin /usr/lib/flashplug
```

I know these are orphaned because the parent pid (PPID) will always be 1.  Similarly I know the process is always an "npviewer.bin" process. I just don't know the magic one liner to identify all these processes and kill them.

Thanks for your help, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  The answer turns out to be

```
pgrep -P1 -f 'npviewer\.bin' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: See also `pkill` - it's comes with `pgrep` and is almost the same - except that it can kill!

Answer (score 1):

Try `killall npviewer.bin` or `killall -9 npviewer.bin` if you're feeling mean.

If you want to discriminate, you'll have to write a script that looks for this info in /proc, or maybe `ps aux | grep npviewer | myscript` to string-hack the neccesary info.

Comment: Your command would kill all running Flash instances, and I only want to kill the orphaned ones.  How do I do that?

Comment: The second example `myscript` can `grep`, `cut`, etc the input to extract the PPID. It won't be portable, but it can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ps -e -o "%P;%p;%c"` to locate the process. The output will be three columns, separated by `;`

The first column must be 1 (PPID) and the last column contains the process name (without arguments). Some versions of ps add the path, some omit it. Trim the line (some versions of `ps` pad the output) and look for the regexp `npviewer.bin$`

If a line matches, kill the process with the PID in column 2.